# Sending user name + encrypted password to a RESTful service

Tags: javascript, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, password-encryption

In my application I am using Spring MVC with a JavaScript client. Now comes the time when I need to add a 4-eyes validation form to my app. That is, a second physical person would have to come by and key in his username and password to validate a sensitive data update of some sort. The system will then check the username and the pwd of that person against an entreprise LDAP and then return successs or failure. If the authentication of that person fails, the system will inform the user that the deletion/addition is not possible. If that succeeds, the system will perform the update.

My question is, since all the services are RESTful, how could I implement such a solution the safest way? I've heard that encrypting the password using a JavaScript API and sending it over the wire should be avoided at all cost as any man-in-the-middle attack could wreak havocs. 
I wouldn't want to use HTTPS either which would only serve that form's purpose which represents a tiny 1% of my app. Should I go for Spring Security? If so how could I integrate a Spring Security web form inside a JavaScript framework? Any thoughts or experience would be more than welcome.

Best,
Jimmy

Answer (score 2):

I would rethink your 'wouldn't want to do it via https and ssl' if security is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a challenge-response mechanism. No passwords will be exchanged.